# java load resource file like ClientBundle GWT

Tags: java, gwt, resources, bundle

I'm writing a Java library, and I found that GWT has ClientBundle interface/class that can use like this:

```
public interface DefaultResources extends ClientBundle
{
    @Source("source/resource.rs")
    TextResource getTextResource();
}
```

How can I achieve that without using GWT?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring DI to achieve this.

```
    @Value("classpath:source/resource.rs")
    Resource myResource;
```

Comment: can I use that with text file and

    String myStrResource;

Comment: You can use it with text file and Resource interface which has `getInputStream` method. If you want to get resource as String, you can make use of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/309448/2221168)